# How to make Ruby variable that will evaluate to false in conditional expressions

Tags: ruby, syntax, conditional-statements, proxy-classes

I want to make my variable (a proxy object) evaluate to false when used in conditional sentences. I know I can use .nil? and even var == nil but I think that's not good enough. What I am trying go do is to:

```
if myproxy # not only myprroxy.nil? or myproxy == nil, but just that
  # myproxy's backend object is not nil
else
  # myproxy's backend object is nil
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The only two objects that evaluate to a false-ish value in a boolean context in Ruby are `nil`, the singleton instance of `NilClass` and `false`, the singleton instance of `FalseClass`. *Every* other object evaluates to a tru-ish value.

If you want that `else` branch to be taken, then `myproxy` *must* evaluate to either `nil` or `false`.

If you want something boolean-ish that you have actual control over, you could try a `case` expression and override the case subsumption operator `MyProxy#===`.

Comment: so Hubert, either `myproxy = nil` or `myproxy = false` should satify you.