# How does Ruby evaluate math expressions to true/false?

Tags: ruby

I am going through the Ruby tutorials from [Learn to Program](http://pine.fm/LearnToProgram/), and I am having a problem with a while loop.

This is what I want to do:

```
while y_now % 4
    y_now += 1
    puts y_now % 4
end
gets
```

I'm using the `gets` just to pause execution so I can see the output. (This is looking for a leap year, btw)

Anyways, when `y_now % 4 = 0`, the while loop continues, and I don't understand why, since this is different from all my previous experience.

I don't want someone to just fix my code though, I really want to understand why this happens. I've obviously just started Ruby, so whatever help I get is very much appreciated.

Note: This seems to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152979/how-to-make-ruby-variable-that-will-evaluate-to-false-in-conditional-expressions), but with integers instead of strings.

Comment: Same answer as [How to make Ruby variable that will evaluate to false in conditional expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152979/how-to-make-ruby-variable-that-will-evaluate-to-false-in-conditional-expressions)

Comment: That's the question I linked to, I just couldn't tell if that extended to mathematical expressions or just strings. (Still new to Ruby)

Comment: I should have linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082341/ifx-vs-ifxfalse-in-ruby/3082399#3082399

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune Your answer there was incredibly helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby only the `nil` object and a special `false` object are "false", everything else (including the integer 0) is "true".  You should use `while (y_now % 4) != 0`.

Comment: OK I got it working now. I am having so much trouble because anytime I have an error, it just exits the command line immediately. Is there any way to have it spit out the error before exiting?

Comment: @phoffer - outputting the error is default behavior, so absence of one might indicate that the script completed successfully without actually doing anything...

Comment: @Matchu I am putting a gets at the end of my scripts for the time being so that it pauses before exiting. When it doesn't get there it just exits. I am opening the files from explorer, launching the command line interface. Should I open the command line first and run them through it that way?

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that before? Answered my own question just now on my own. Thanks Matchu. Is there a way to have it output the error without exiting if I launch them from explorer?

Comment: @phoffer - ahh, there ya go. I've run into this numerous times for bash scripts and the like - it hits an error, but the window disappears before I can read it, since the program is technically finished. Glad to help xD As far as a fix goes, there's probably not a clean way, but maybe you can be creative :/

Comment: Maybe after I get used to putting a 20 line script together without 8 revisions :) I do like it though (used to php), just gotta get used to it.